# Serve default files from within static file directory

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-2.0, lets-encrypt, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I'm trying to configure a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate with an As.Net Core 2.0 MVC Web App in Azure.

I have gotten to the point where I'm able to serve the file

http://xxx.yyy.zz/.well-known/acme-challenge/{ChallengeValue}/Index.html. I did that using the UseStaticFiles configuration method:

```cs
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
  FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @".well-known")),
                RequestPath = new PathString("/.well-known"),
                ServeUnknownFileTypes = true // serve extensionless files
});
```

It seems my next challenge is to make it serve the Index.html file automatically when accessing the following:

- http://xxx.yyy.zz/.well-known/acme-challenge/{ChallengeValue}/
- http://xxx.yyy.zz/.well-known/acme-challenge/{ChallengeValue}

My first idea was to simply use the app.UseDefaultFiles() to enable this, but that does not seem to work for the path defined using app.UseStaticFiles(...). Not even hardcoding the value as a path like `app.UseDefaultFiles(".//.well-known/acme-challenge/{ChallengeValue}")` works.

The solution needs to support a dynamic value of `{ChallengeValue}`.

Thanks in advance

Søren Rokkedal